# Reciting yizkor for non-observant parents

Tags: halacha, tefilla, yoreh-deah, yizkor, observance

Is there anything problematic in Halacha with Jews reciting yizkor for deceased parents who were non-observant when they were alive? Or no, should it be recited even if they were not observant or religious?

Comment: What do you think the issue with this might be?